# What's the correct parameter to resize a cluster? [GCP]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster in GCP that I want to resize using the console command. I was looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/resize) when I've realized that it's possible to resize the cluster with:

```
gcloud container clusters resize [CLUSTER_NAME] --node-pool [NODE_POOL] --num-nodes [NUM_NODES] --region=$REGION
```

and either

```
gcloud container clusters resize [CLUSTER_NAME] --node-pool [NODE_POOL] --size [NUM_NODES] --region=$REGION
```

I have tried and seems like both work properly but is there any difference? which is better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands are actually identical and have the same effect. The original `--size` flag was renamed `--num-nodes` since it's more self-explanatory. This was introduced in version 242.0.0 and is documented in the [Cloud SDK release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#kubernetes_engine_8):

> Renamed `--size` flag of gcloud container clusters resize to
>   `--num-nodes`. `--size` retained as an alias.